# Print full pathname with `ls` and `find`

Tags: find, ls

I want `ls` to print with absolute pathnames, how do I do that?

```
find / -type d -mount -exec ls -ls  {} \;
```

`ls` is printing only the relative file names within the directory.

Comment: Use `ls -lsd` instead of only `ls -ls`?

Comment: What do you want to see? Directories only? The contents of the directories with absolute file names? What OS are you on? Can we assume GNU find?

Comment: I use Ubuntu ...

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
find / -xdev -type d -exec sh -c 'for d; do ls -lsd "$d"/*; done' sh {} +
```

`-xdev` has the same affect as `-mount` but is portable.

A note that this will fail on empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

That is the usual behaviour of `ls` when a directory is given as argument. So you have to avoid `ls` handling directories specially.

1. You must pass file paths to `ls`, i.e. `-type f` instead of `-type d`.
2. If you want to pass directories, too, (no `-type f`) then you need the option `-d` for `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the command to execute to `echo`:

```
find / -type d -mount -exec echo {} \;
```